# NgOptimizedImage against a URL

Tags: angular

I upgraded my Angular 14.0 to 14.2 so that I could use the NgOptimizedImage. The documentation shows that against an <img control instead of using src, ngSrc should be used:

```
ngSrc="logo.png"
```

however, my source is a url and so appears not to work. Has anyone managed to use the ngOptimazeImage against a url as opposed to a hard coded file name that I assume would reside in your assets file?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to include all the required directives in the img tag.

Either

```
<img ngSrc="logo.png" width="200" height="300">
```

OR

```
<img ngSrc="logo.png" fill>
```

---

**With a valid URL**

```
<img ngSrc="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/14.jpg" width="200" height="300">
```

OR

```
<img ngSrc="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/14.jpg" fill>
```